# What is the aircraft model used in the film "American Made"?

Tags: piston-engine, aircraft-identification, multi-engine, beechcraft

In [American Made](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3532216/), what is the model of the white airplane that the CIA presents to [Barry Seal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Seal) (played by Tom Cruise)? He says something along the lines of "the fastest piston twin". Are those continental engines?

Comment: You can use [IMPDb](http://www.impdb.org/index.php?title=American_Made) for aircraft in movies (and users of this stack can contribute to it).

Answer (score 14):

[If you are talking about the one prevalent in this trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEBIJRAkujM) its an [Piper Aerostar 600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_Aerostar). The tail number is legitimate and the [full registration details for 164HH can be found here](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=164HH).

[Some of the movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goS3L4hp1oI) may also have utilized a [Beech Queen Air Model 88](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_Queen_Air)

Answer (score 4):

It is an Aerostar, most likely the fastest GA piston twin ever, except for its little sisters and brothers, the 602   602p   700 series.   It was designed by  visionary Ted Smith.  Its airframe is strong enough to support turbopops and jets, which Smith envisioned for the future.    A slick, fuel efficient plane, very strong.   Large wing loading makes it cut through turbulence like butter.   Underwear changing sink rate, so have to keep them fast.   Probably my favorite of my imaginary planes I have not yet flown in real life.

Comment: The very plane from the movie [crashed](https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/179500) on Sep. 11, 2015 in Colombia.